# Helping users with reputation 1 and automatically assigned names?

Tags: discussion, new-users

Lately, I'm becoming reluctant to help users who have reputation count 1 and who have an automatically assigned name. From my short experience they tend to make questions (usually homework), you help them and when they get what they want they disappear. They add nothing to the community, they don't collaborate and rarely up vote answers.

What is your strategy in handling these cases?

Comment: I tend to answer questions when I either find them interesting or when I know the answer and can write up a solution fairly quickly. Paying attentioin to the username or rep of the OP has never really occured to me.

Comment: Evaluate the question, regardless of rep, name, age or avatar of the user. Bad question? Downvote, possibly closevote, optionally comment, move on. Good question? Upvote, answer, whatever.

Comment: I'm not surprised they don't up vote, at that comes with 50 rep...

Comment: @matsjoyce, that's not correct. Upvoting privilege comes with 15 reputation.

Comment: Sorry, got confused with commenting. 15 then.

Comment: My strategy is to check my history periodically for questions I answered which have been deleted and ask the mods to restore them. If the question is worth answering and the answer is good, they will restore it and you will get your rep from others. (I soothe myself with the idea that they might get in trouble with their professor if they're cheating--as is likely, if they delete the question after getting the answer.)

Comment: @Daniel Lyons the thing about the professor... :)  never saw it that way. Nice.

Comment: We all had rep 1 once (well, except those that got an automatic 100 rep from another SE site).

Comment: @MattBurland "those" too. We all had to start somewhere!

Comment: @MattBurland Some of us association rep users started the SE network on SO and just got really good in another site afterwords. :)

Comment: In my experience, new users just don't seem understand the site and or don't know how to up vote. But, ultimately, we're here to help; not to just be concerned with rep and badges... Those should remain secondary...

Comment: @djm +1 for being comprehensive with those not understanding the site. However, at least a "Thanks" would be appreciated by those asking help. Ultimately, you spend your time researching and finding answers to help others.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Judge the question by the question - If they have spent time making a good question, they'll generally hang around long enough to mark the answer that helped them.

Even if not, the community will provide upvotes where needed.

If the question looks poor - downvote it/vote to close it/ignore it. Sure, there are more of them from these kinds of users, but it's by no means exclusively something you see from them. I don't think it takes longer to judge a question correctly than it does to look at the user. You can generally tell at a glance.

Comment: I like your answer, but I'll leave the question open for a little bit as I would like to hear more standpoints. Although, it seams like others think like you.

Answer (score 53):

The [answer given by Lattyware](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/275674/839601) is the correct answer of course.  However it's easy to think like that when you have a ton of rep and no longer care about it any more - when you're keen to build yours up it can be very frustrating answering drive-by questions again and again and getting nothing in return for it and it's tempting to start being selective.

Give it time though. If the question is worth answering and you answer it well then it will be found in future by SO users who are maybe more appreciative of your efforts.  You sometimes find that an answer you gave years ago still gets upvotes even though the OP is long gone (indeed, was gone 5 minutes after you gave your answer).  Who cares if it's not marked as the correct answer, it's helping people.

So bear that in mind when you find SO answers on Google that help you out, my policy in such a case (which is about 20 times a day) is to upvote question and answer(s)

Comment: That's a absolute correct point from my experience in SO.

Comment: Agreed as well. Note there are two badges that are kind of easily awarded by answering new users questions: [Tenacious](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/225/tenacious) and [Unsung Hero](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/226/unsung-hero), because: 1) New users can't upvote. 2) Most of time questions are not high quality and thus people tend to ignore those questions. In consequence you get an accepted answer with no up-votes. Consolation prize, I guess :P

Comment: I agree except when a question has 10k+ views, 1 correct 0 votes and not accepted answer... those cases are sad

Answer (score 13):

I agree with [Lattyware's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/275674/839601) in general: questions should be judged on the question, not the questioner.

However, when you've judged a question and found it lacking, then it *can* be worth looking at the username and rep. Why? Well, a bad question is a bad question, but…

- A bad question asked by a 1-rep generic-name user, there's at least a chance that giving him a little more guidance in a comment will be enough to prompt him to go read the help.
- A bad question asked by a 80000-rep user with a familiar name, maybe it's worth taking a second look to see if I've misjudged it
- A bad question by a long-time user who's still under 50 rep, don't waste any more time.

Comment: Very interesting the three points you listed. +1

Answer (score 5):

I'm new enough to the Stack Exchange group that I can remember having my first couple of posts edited to improve the content so I try not to ignore or disparage users with a 1 reputation even if they have been down-voted for not providing non-functional attempts or sample data. With that said, I think that anyone with even a small amount of experience responding to questions can recognize a copy & paste from a homework question or an inquiry that shows zero effort on the part of the OP.

I don't think that all homework questions are to be completely ignored, particularly so if the OP has made at least some amount of effort and come to an impasse where they are unfamiliar with the concepts and methods available within the platform they are working under. In at some small way, pretty much all Q&A exchanges within these forums are a form of tutoring but providing 'turn-key' solutions as opposed to 'teach-a-man-to-fish' answers should be avoided. In my own sandbox (Excel), obfuscating a reply sufficiently that the OP would have to interpret the proposed solution for their own purposes instead of copying & pasting it back into their homework might be enough to get them to actually think about the answer. If they cannot get it working beyond the sample data I may have created or from their own redacted sample data to the actual operational data, they will usually come back with a comment.

With regard to the 'zero original effort' posts, I have my own barometer on scoping the validity of the question. Simply count the number of occurrences of the phrase *I want...* and you will get a good indication of whether assistance should be offered or a comment posted directing the OP to oDesk or Freelancer. By the third *I want...*, I've given up reading and my cursor is moving to the down-vote button.

A subset of the 'zero original effort' poster is one who habitually posts as a first-time user. I believe I'm starting to recognize a few of these and will often Google a quoted string from their posts to see how may cross-posts they have submitted to other sites. I'm talking about users who could not be bothered to remember their previous log-in credentials or even take the time to go through the lost password process. They have found that they can post with little to no effort on their own and come back in a couple of days for a result. They may have even discarded previous first-time log-ins due to a negative reputation that was correctly assigned. I have zero patience with these OPs. FWIW, I've found a few googled returns coming from posted jobs on the freelancing sites mentioned earlier so that would seem to indicate that not only are these low-brows accepting work they cannot perform, they are expecting public help forums to do their work for them.

So I guess I'm saying that you shouldn't give up on a bad post by a 1 just for not following the rules. Perhaps one in a hundred new users read any of the Help or FAQ before attempting their first post and that figure is pretty optimistic. Remember that they have already reached some level of frustration before coming here to ask for help and if they show some effort on their end, then I'll at least read their inquiry to see if I can shed some light on their issue.